# Pod not found in Istio service mesh, but has side car present

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Been struggling to debug a 503 response on my cluster, after checking the gateway, virtual service, ports, routes, etc., I came across a suggestion on [istio's docs for the describe](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/istioctl-describe/) command to check if the pods are present in the mesh.

Running istioctl x describe pod -n demoapp frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m returns:

```
Error: pods "frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m" not found
```

However the namespace is labeled for auto-injection:

```
Name:         demoapp
Labels:       istio-injection=enabled
              kubernetes.io/metadata.name=demoapp
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No LimitRange resource.
```

The pod itself shows the inject label and has the sidecar attached:

```
Name:             frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m
Namespace:        demoapp
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             gke-demo-istio-default-pool-0565dc58-wdgc/10.168.0.37
Start Time:       Tue, 09 Jan 2024 14:40:58 -0800
Labels:           app=frontend
                  istio=ingressgateway
                  pod-template-hash=56b859c549
                  security.istio.io/tlsMode=istio
                  service.istio.io/canonical-name=frontend
                  service.istio.io/canonical-revision=latest
                  sidecar.istio.io/inject=true
Annotations:      istio.io/rev: default
                  kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: frontend
                  kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-logs-container: frontend
                  prometheus.io/path: /stats/prometheus
                  prometheus.io/port: 15020
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
                  sidecar.istio.io/status:
                    {"initContainers":["istio-init"],"containers":["istio-proxy"],"volumes":["workload-socket","credential-socket","workload-certs","istio-env...
Status:           Running
```

istioctl proxy-status shows the proxies in place:

```
NAME                                                  CLUSTER        CDS        LDS        EDS        RDS          ECDS         ISTIOD                      VERSION
backend-deploy-7b67c75996-v94km.demoapp               Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       NOT SENT     istiod-6c7b79d8cc-j4dtx     1.20.1
frontend-deploy-6cc895d79b-rxbrk.demoapp              Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       NOT SENT     istiod-6c7b79d8cc-j4dtx     1.20.1
istio-egressgateway-5978d8c44b-rbnmf.istio-system     Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     NOT SENT     NOT SENT     istiod-6c7b79d8cc-j4dtx     1.20.0
istio-ingressgateway-6d6469f44-ckddk.istio-system     Kubernetes     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       NOT SENT     istiod-6c7b79d8cc-j4dtx     1.20.1
```

and proxy seems to be in good shape:

```
istioctl ps frontend-deploy-6cc895d79b-rxbrk.demoapp
Clusters Match
Listeners Match
Routes Match (RDS last loaded at Wed, 10 Jan 2024 16:13:46 PST)
```

Also, the logs for the proxy container seem to show that it is running with no errors:

```
k logs frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m -c istio-proxy -n demoapp
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417349Z info    FLAG: --concurrency="0"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417554Z info    FLAG: --domain="demoapp.svc.cluster.local"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417663Z info    FLAG: --help="false"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417740Z info    FLAG: --log_as_json="false"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417831Z info    FLAG: --log_caller=""
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417898Z info    FLAG: --log_output_level="default:info"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.417975Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate=""
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418042Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_age="30"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418122Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_backups="1000"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418209Z info    FLAG: --log_rotate_max_size="104857600"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418293Z info    FLAG: --log_stacktrace_level="default:none"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418417Z info    FLAG: --log_target="[stdout]"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418508Z info    FLAG: --meshConfig="./etc/istio/config/mesh"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418576Z info    FLAG: --outlierLogPath=""
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418655Z info    FLAG: --profiling="true"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418726Z info    FLAG: --proxyComponentLogLevel="misc:error"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418805Z info    FLAG: --proxyLogLevel="warning"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418870Z info    FLAG: --serviceCluster="istio-proxy"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.418946Z info    FLAG: --stsPort="0"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.419014Z info    FLAG: --templateFile=""
2024-01-09T22:41:00.419093Z info    FLAG: --tokenManagerPlugin="GoogleTokenExchange"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.419160Z info    FLAG: --vklog="0"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.419239Z info    Version 1.20.1-552626bd81f625917bcba6e415cae5aa3d5c61af-Clean
2024-01-09T22:41:00.425348Z info    Maximum file descriptors (ulimit -n): 1048576
2024-01-09T22:41:00.425855Z info    Proxy role  ips=[10.24.1.37] type=sidecar id=frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m.demoapp domain=demoapp.svc.cluster.local
2024-01-09T22:41:00.426208Z info    Apply proxy config from env {}

2024-01-09T22:41:00.429884Z info    cpu limit detected as 2, setting concurrency
2024-01-09T22:41:00.431268Z info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
concurrency: 2
configPath: ./etc/istio/proxy
controlPlaneAuthPolicy: MUTUAL_TLS
discoveryAddress: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
drainDuration: 45s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
serviceCluster: istio-proxy
statNameLength: 189
statusPort: 15020
terminationDrainDuration: 5s
tracing:
  zipkin:
    address: zipkin.istio-system:9411

2024-01-09T22:41:00.431673Z info    JWT policy is third-party-jwt
2024-01-09T22:41:00.431820Z info    using credential fetcher of JWT type in cluster.local trust domain
2024-01-09T22:41:00.435453Z info    platform detected is GCP
2024-01-09T22:41:00.437364Z info    Workload SDS socket not found. Starting Istio SDS Server
2024-01-09T22:41:00.437556Z info    CA Endpoint istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, provider Citadel
2024-01-09T22:41:00.437752Z info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2024-01-09T22:41:00.438509Z info    Opening status port 15020
2024-01-09T22:41:00.515254Z info    ads All caches have been synced up in 98.386567ms, marking server ready
2024-01-09T22:41:00.538705Z info    xdsproxy    Initializing with upstream address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" and cluster "Kubernetes"
2024-01-09T22:41:00.541662Z info    sds Starting SDS grpc server
2024-01-09T22:41:00.543051Z info    starting Http service at 127.0.0.1:15004
2024-01-09T22:41:00.573439Z info    Pilot SAN: [istiod.istio-system.svc]
2024-01-09T22:41:00.577805Z info    Starting proxy agent
2024-01-09T22:41:00.577853Z info    starting
2024-01-09T22:41:00.580330Z info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev.json --drain-time-s 45 --drain-strategy immediate --local-address-ip-version v4 --file-flush-interval-msec 1000 --disable-hot-restart --allow-unknown-static-fields --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ   %l  envoy %n %g:%#  %v  thread=%t -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
2024-01-09T22:41:00.701090Z info    cache   generated new workload certificate  latency=184.848904ms ttl=23h59m59.298936103s
2024-01-09T22:41:00.701361Z info    cache   Root cert has changed, start rotating root cert
2024-01-09T22:41:00.701643Z info    ads XDS: Incremental Pushing ConnectedEndpoints:0 Version:
2024-01-09T22:41:00.701856Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.298146362s
2024-01-09T22:41:00.742188Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-09T22:41:00.782569Z info    ads ADS: new connection for node:frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m.demoapp-2
2024-01-09T22:41:00.782734Z info    cache   returned workload trust anchor from cache   ttl=23h59m59.217269213s
2024-01-09T22:41:00.782584Z info    ads ADS: new connection for node:frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m.demoapp-1
2024-01-09T22:41:00.783115Z info    cache   returned workload certificate from cache    ttl=23h59m59.216887621s
2024-01-09T22:41:00.783459Z info    ads SDS: PUSH request for node:frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m.demoapp resources:1 size:1.1kB resource:ROOTCA
2024-01-09T22:41:00.783590Z info    ads SDS: PUSH request for node:frontend-deploy-56b859c549-h464m.demoapp resources:1 size:4.0kB resource:default
2024-01-09T22:41:01.080473Z info    Readiness succeeded in 682.678666ms
2024-01-09T22:41:01.081252Z info    Envoy proxy is ready
2024-01-09T23:08:32.131721Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-09T23:39:59.114540Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T00:09:53.199920Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T00:40:05.998503Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T01:13:13.705910Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T01:43:08.229709Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T02:14:35.992319Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T02:44:19.942498Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T03:14:32.785464Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T03:41:47.747331Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T04:13:51.289590Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T04:45:31.397695Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T05:16:25.746777Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2024-01-10T05:47:12.503887Z info    xdsproxy    connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
```

I'm totally at a loss of how to debug this further, or if the fact that istioctl x describe did not recognize the pods/ services is just a false lead and the proxies/pods are running fine. However this is the closest to finding a reason why my mesh is not reachable from outside that I've come. Everything else seems to be working. Any suggestions on where else to look to debug would be greatly appreciated. Running on GKE if that makes a difference.

Comment: Can you check the [link](https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/#support-status-of-istio-releases) for the supported versions. As per the information provided , you are using Istio 1.20.1 and the corresponding supported Kubernetes versions are 1.25, 1.26, 1.27, 1.28 .

Comment: @KiranKotturi I'm running kubernetes 1.28: Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"28", GitVersion:"v1.28.3-gke.1203001", GitCommit:"28396c07d85d0131e4f94369f78a7dee01ca1e0c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-10-26T09:28:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.10 X:boringcrypto", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Can you check the [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63261742/20917133) and let me know if it is useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, I had gone over that post before. I'm trying to get it running under GKE with gateway API, which is failing due to GKE have more strict requirements for health probes (i think thats why anyway). Once I get this dialed in, I'll try again with Istio, since I found no errors anywhere

Answer (score -1):

you do know you got the wrong CLI command format:

```
istioctl experimental describe pod mypodname.myappnamespace
```

do not use `-n` with describe command
this is wrong: `istioctl x describe pod -n demoapp....`

Comment: Its the shorthand for the flag, its even in their docs  https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/